# My application crashes if i get no records from SQLite

Tags: iphone, sqlite, select

I'm working with SQlite for the first time....
I look up a discount in the DB, and every things works fine, until i select "nothing". This happens if the amount (adNumbers) is higher or lower than specified in the DB.

Then when trying to retrieve discount value from the DB column i get an error and application crashes. I have tried to make a NULL check, but that doesn't seems to help/work.

I have tried to use 
 `while( sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW){`

but the i don't get anything returned at all...

Please point me in the right direction - how do i check if the DB returns any records (adNumbers are between values en the DB )

This is my method..

`-(NSString *) adDisq:(NSString *)strDISQ:(NSInteger)adNumbers{`

```
NSString *strDiscount;
strDiscount = @"00";

if(adSTMT == nil) {
    const char *sql = "SELECT ID, DISCOUNT_TYPE, DESCRIPTION, AD_FROM, AD_TO, AD_DISQ FROM DISCOUNT "
                      "WHERE (((DISCOUNT_TYPE)=?) AND ((?) Between AD_FROM And AD_TO))";

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &adSTMT, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating detail view statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}

sqlite3_bind_text(adSTMT, 1, [strDISQ UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
sqlite3_bind_int(adSTMT, 2, adNumbers);   

if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(adSTMT)) {
    NSLog(@"SELECT went OK, getting rows");
    const char *columnText = (const char *)sqlite3_column_text(adSTMT, 5);
    if(columnText != NULL){
        strDiscount = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(adSTMT, 5)];
        NSLog(@"Discount: %@", strDiscount);
    }
    else {
        strDiscount = @"00";
    }
}
else{
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error while getting the discount'%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}

//Reset the detail statement.
sqlite3_reset(adSTMT);
return strDiscount;
```

}

Comment: your application crashes when data is absent or data does not exist in specified range ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved

NSAssert1(0, @"Error while getting the discount'%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

Was making the crash - as expected - doh !